# Was the painting “In the Ring of Saturn” by artist Andrei Sokolov used as a book cover?

Tags: books, art, cover-art

The BBC News exposé ['Our Saturn years'; Cassini's epic journey to the ringed planet, told by the people who helped make it happen](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/resources/idt-sh/cassini_huygens_saturn) includes the text:

> “The Voyagers gave us a really wonderful impression of Saturn. It’s a beautiful gas giant,” says Nasa’s director of planetary science Jim Green.
>
> Prof Andrew Coates, from the Mullard Space Science Laboratory in Surrey, UK, agrees:
>
> “Saturn is the most spectacular planet in our Solar System. The incredible rings, visible even in binoculars or a small telescope, make it stand out compared to all the rest.”
>
> In places, the rings are only about as tall as a telephone pole. Yet from end-to-end they are more than 20-times as wide as the Earth.
>
> **They have influenced decades of science fiction book covers.**

Followed by a reproduction of the painting *In the Ring of Saturn* by artist Andrei Sokolov.

The painting is stylized and shows a spacecraft beaming something to the planet Saturn, with the suggestions of the planet's rings in the background, all in various shades of green and yellow.

**Question:** But there is no indication that this art is related to any specific book cover. So I would like to ask; Was the painting “In the Ring of Saturn” by artist Andrei Sokolov used as a book cover? If not, was any of this artist's work used in book covers?

Per [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Andrei_Konstantinovich_Sokolov):

> Andrei Konstantinovich Sokolov (1931—2007) was a Soviet and Russian science fiction painter and a graphic artist, a designer of stamps, an architect.

---

For some other examples of work by the artist, see for example

- https://vintagetech.blognook.com/?s=sokolov&submit=Go
- http://www.artnet.com/artists/andrei-sokolov/
- https://gizmodo.com/the-first-spacewalker-and-his-painter-friend-created-th-1729276737
- https://www.pinterest.com/nikosretiniotis/andrei-sokolov/
- https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Andrei_Konstantinovich_Sokolov

> Reproduction of “In the Ring of Saturn” by artist Andrei Sokolov
> (Topfoto)

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ISFDb page for [Andrei Konstantinovich Sokolov](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?25103) (Андрей Константинович Соколов) does not list "In the Ring of Saturn" as one of the works that have been published as cover art.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy answer, and for mentioning ISFDb, I didn't know of it until now!